# Помощь в разработке алгоритма

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ребята, всем привет. Вообщем, все бьюсь над разработкой приложения графов. Сделал графическую отрисовку, расстановку точек, но самое главное - подсчет минимального пути не могу ничего придумать.
Отрисовка точек проходит по следующему методу:
В `EditText editT`,в первой Активити вписывается ( пример ):

```
AB 15;
BC 13;
CD 30;
AD 50;
DH 69;
CH 79;
```

на этом строится граф :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне нужно на данный момент программно создать пути, тобишь AB-BC-CH, AB-BC-CD-DH и т.д, чтобы в дальнейшем высчитать минимальное расстояние и показать его и мин.расстояние ( от выбраной точки, до конечной точки). Пробывал через циклы,помешая все пути в массив, типо:

```
for(int i = 0;i<array.size();i++){
point = array.get(i).toCharArray(); // char элемента Array
if (startPoint == point[0]){   // если этот элемент начало точки. startPoint - нач. точка
while (point[1]!=stopPoint){ // цикл stopPoint - кнч. точка
point2= array.get(k).toCharArray(); // второй элемент цепочки в char
if(point[1] == point2[0]) {// если АС - СB то
```

Но ничего особого не выходит, выручайте

Comment: Старик [Дейсктра](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Дейкстры) давно всё придумал

Comment: Согласен, но ненашел применения по его методу

Answer (score 0):

это должно вам помочь:

```
/*
Реализуйте алгоритм Дейкстры поиска кратчайшего пути в графе.
Входные данные: В первой строке указаны два числа: число вершин и число ребер графа. 
Далее идут строки с описанием ребер. Их количество равно числу ребер. 
В каждой строке указаны 3 числа: исходящая вершина, входящая вершина, вес ребра. 
В последней строке указаны 2 номера вершины: начальная и конечная вершина, кратчайший путь между которыми нужно найти.
Выходные данные: минимальное расстояние между заданными вершинами. Если пути нет, то нужно вернуть -1.
Sample Input:
4 8
1 2 6
1 3 2
1 4 10
2 4 4
3 1 5
3 2 3
3 4 8
4 2 1
1 4
Sample Output:
9
*/
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
private static List<Rib> ribs;
private static int peaksCount, ribsCount;
private static int taskFrom, taskTo;

private static class Rib {
    int from;
    int to;
    int weight;

    private Rib(int from, int to, int weight) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}   

private static void initialize(Scanner in) {
    peaksCount = in.nextInt();
    ribsCount = in.nextInt();
    ribs = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < ribsCount; i++) {
        ribs.add(new Rib(in.nextInt(), in.nextInt(), in.nextInt()));
    }
    taskFrom = in.nextInt();
    taskTo = in.nextInt();
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    initialize(in);

    if(ribsCount != 0) {
        List<Integer> usedPeaks = new LinkedList<>();
        usedPeaks.add(taskFrom);
        int currentPeak = taskFrom;
        int result = 0; 

        //костыль на случай, если из заданного старта есть прямой
        //путь в заданный финиш, т.к. итоговый путь может оказаться
        //больше него
        int directLineWeight = 0; 
        for(Rib r : ribs) {
            if(r.from == taskFrom && r.to == taskTo) {
                directLineWeight = r.weight;
            }
        }

        while(currentPeak != taskTo && usedPeaks.size() != peaksCount) {
            List<Rib> currentRibsList = new LinkedList<>();

            //составляем список возможных для использования ребер
            for(Rib r : ribs) {
                if (r.from == currentPeak && !usedPeaks.contains(r.to)) {
                    currentRibsList.add(r);
                }
            }

            //если не найдено ни одного подходящего ребра
            if(currentRibsList.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println(-1);
                return;
            }
            ribs.removeAll(currentRibsList);

            //ищем в этом списке ребро, с использованием которого 
            //удастся достичь наименьшего НА ДАННЫЙ МОМЕНТ веса
            int minWeight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            Rib ribToUse = null;
            for(Rib r : currentRibsList) {
                if(r.weight + result < minWeight) {
                    minWeight = r.weight;
                    ribToUse = r;
                }
            }
            currentRibsList.remove(ribToUse);
            ribs.addAll(currentRibsList);

            //меняем текущие значения для переменных-показателей статуса
            currentPeak = ribToUse.to;
            usedPeaks.add(ribToUse.to);
            result += ribToUse.weight;

            //выводит список вершин, обойденных на данный момент
            /*for(int r : usedPeaks) {
                System.out.print(r);
            }
            System.out.println();*/
        }

        //если нужного пути не существует, выводится -1
        if(currentPeak != taskTo &&  usedPeaks.size() == peaksCount){
            System.out.println(-1);     
        } else {
            if(directLineWeight != 0 && result > directLineWeight) {
                System.out.println(directLineWeight);
            } else {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(-1);
    }
}
}
```